# QDesktopServices openUrl does not open

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use QDesktopServices to open a directory defined as cpath.

```
QString openPath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(cpath);
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(cpath, QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

However the above code does not do anything.

The code is put in a function which is bound to a button using connect().
I have tested that the connect function works by creating a QMessageBox that opens when the button is clicked.

```
connect(openButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OpenDirectory()));
```

Code:

```
void QtReader::OpenDirectory()
{
     QString openPath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(cpath);
     QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile( qApp- 
     ApplicationDirPath()+QDir::separator()+"ReaderArchives")); //current working code
}
```

cpath declaration:

```
  QString cpath = qApp->applicationDirPath()+QDir::separator()+"ReaderArchives";
```

Header File

```
public:
    explicit QtReader(QWidget *parent = 0);
     ~QtReader();
     QString cpath, spath, tpath;
```

Comment: Why are you calling toNativeSeparators (and not using the result) ?

Comment: What does `cpath` look like? Also, remove teh second argument from `QUrl` constructor.

Comment: cpath is qApp->applicationDirPath() + QDir::separator(). Also toNativeSeparators was test code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your url is interpreted as a local file path, try this:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(cpath));
```

note that there is no need to use `QDir::toNativeSeparators()`, the conversion is done automatically this way.

**EDIT:**

Your *declaration* of `cpath` is the cause of your problem, I am not sure what you meant, and where are you putting your *decleration* , but I think You are declaring a new variable with the same name `cpath` that has another scope, and then in your `OpenDirectory()` you are referring the uninitialized member QString `cpath`, that haven't been assigned to any value yet, so omit your *decleration* and in your constructor assign a value to the member `cpath` this way:

```
cpath = qApp->applicationDirPath()+QDir::separator()+"ReaderArchives";
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the same result occurs. Whenever I click the button, The folder isn't opened.

Comment: and there is no debug output?? check for error messages there

Comment: this worked for me when `cpath = qApp->applicationDirPath()` and it opened the application's directory

Comment: please tell us what qt version you are using and on what OS

Comment: I'm writing it on windows, but it is planned for use on linux using QT 5.5. Directly using     QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile( qApp->applicationDirPath())); works but if I pass QString cpath, it doesn't work. Also debug output is just "Debugging starts
Debugging has finished"

Comment: It seems Qt doesn't open the directory, if the QUrl argument is a variable which is odd.

Comment: @Akito, that's not true, I declared cpath as a QString and it worked. I think there might be another problem in your code. Try posting all the code.

Comment: I just posted all the code for the use and declaration of cpath within that function.

Comment: Have you removed the `QUrl::TolerantMode` flag ?

Comment: @Akito from the code you posted, cpath seems not to be a local variable. so try printing it out before passing it to `QUrl::fromLocalFile`, use `qDebug("%s", cpath.toLocal8Bit().data());` and make sure it contains the right string

Comment: @IIya I already removed the QUrl::Tolerant Flag, the change was shown above.

Comment: @Mike I'm not getting an output from qt using qDebug.

Comment: @Akito your string isn't initialized correctly then, to make sure you are using qDebug right,do `QString test("test"); qDebug("%s", test.toLocal8Bit().data());` if that did output _test_ then you can be sure that the error is in the string initialization, maybe the function that initializes it isn't called or something like that.

Comment: @Akito , your decleration of cpath just got my attention, you have to just assign this value to it in the constructor, not sure what you meant with your writing , but you should do it in your constructor definition this way: `cpath =  qApp->applicationDirPath()+QDir::separator()+"ReaderArchives";`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for **[`QDesktopService::openUrl(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl)** it is expecting a URL that indicates the [scheme name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) which for a local file is: `file` - this is prepended when you use the **[`QUrl::fromLocalFile(const QString & pathFileName)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromLocalFile)** form but it does not seem to me that you are adding the needed `file://` prefix in your original, non-working code.